# Solving $\frac{8}{1-\cos(4x)} = \frac{5}{\tan^2(2x)} + 3$, I keep getting only one answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to solve the following and I keep only getting one answer.

$$\dfrac{8}{1-\cos(4x)} = \dfrac{5}{\tan^2(2x)} + 3$$

Firstly, I see that one can set the denominators of the two fractions each equivalent to $1$. I tried that and I got the same answer both times: $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$.

Then, re-writing the problem as:
$$\dfrac{8}{2\sin^2(2x)} = \dfrac{5\cos^2(2x)}{1-\cos^2(2x)} + 3 \tag1$$

and again as:
$$\dfrac{4}{\sin^2(2x)} = \dfrac{5\cos^2(2x)}{\sin^2(2x)} + \dfrac{3\sin^2(2x)}{\sin^2(2x)} \tag2$$

and again as:
$$4 = 5\cos^2(2x) + 3\sin^2(2x) \tag3$$

and then solving, I got:

$$\sin(2x) =  \dfrac{\sqrt2}{2} \tag4$$
which again solved as
$$\dfrac{\pi}{8} + \dfrac{\pi k}{4} \tag5$$

The answer says that there is an additional answer:
$$\pm \dfrac{2\pi}{3} + \dfrac{\pi k}{2} \tag6$$
but I can't seem to figure out where I lost that answer along the way. Any ideas?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B8%2C1-Cos%5B4x%5D%5D%3D+Divide%5B5%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29Tan%5B2x%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2B3) doesn't give $\frac{2\pi}3$ as an answer.

Comment: Did you plug that additional answer into the original problem?

Comment: In (4) I think you mean $\sin(2x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. (5) is then correct.

Comment: $\frac {2\pi}3$ does not make the original equation true.

Answer (score 6):

I also fail to find the second answer ... because it does not hold. When $x=2\pi/3$ is plugged into the original equation, the left side is $16/3$ and the right side is $14/3$.

Your solutions are entirely correct except for the fact that you apparently missed a sign in Eq. (4). Properly,

$\sin(2x)=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}2.$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{8}{1-\cos 4x}= \frac{5}{\tan^2 2x}+3$

$4 \cdot \frac{2}{1- \cos 4x}= \frac{4}{\sin^2 2x}$

$4=5\cos^2 2x + 3 \sin^2 2x = 3+2\cos^2x$

$1=2\cos^2 2x$

$\cos 2x = \pm \sqrt{2}/2$

$2x= \pi/4 + k\pi/2$

$x= \pi/8+k\pi/4$

---

Suppose $ x = \pm 2\pi/3+\pi k/2$

Then $2x = \pm 4\pi/3 + \pi k $

$\cos 2x = \cos (\pm 4\pi/3)\cos(\pi k)-\sin(\pm 4\pi/3)\sin(\pi k)$

$\cos 2x = (-1/2)(-1)^k$

$\cos ^2 2x = (1/4)$

$\sin ^2 2x = 3/4$

$\tan^2 2x = 3$

$2 \cos^2 2x =1/2<1$

$16/3 \ne 5/3+3 =14/3 $

So the extra solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After coming to your 3 rd equation, you can express the result as $ Cos4x = 0 $ and it gives general solutions as follows, 
$Cos4x = Cosπ/2 $
$4x = 2nπ ± π/2 $
$x = nπ/2 ± π/8 $ ,  $   n∈ ℤ$

Comment: @OscarLanzi when$ n $ is $0$  you get  $π /8$ and   -$ π/8  $both.

Comment: Missed a sign. Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the problem simpler using
$$\dfrac{8}{1-\cos(4x)} -\left( \dfrac{5}{\tan^2(2x)} + 3\right)=-\cos (4 x) \csc ^2(2 x)$$

Another way : use $x=\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}(t)$ to make $1-\frac{1}{t^2}=0$